# Deploy ESX virtual machine from template with esxcli

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vcenter

I have an ESXi 5.0 and VirtualCenter setup. I've created a VM template (let's call it rhel-template) and I want to deploy it from the command-line (via esxcli).

How do I do so?

Comment: Not tempted to use autodeploy and host profiles?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do from esxcli or from the ESXi host.
Template functions are related to vCenter Center with PowerCLI.
Have a look at: http://blog.vmpros.nl/2011/01/16/vmware-deploy-multiple-vms-from-template-with-powercli/